# How - Spring integration: reliable delivery even application crash

Tags: spring-integration

Now we use QueueChannel with JDBC message store to persist the message, with a transactional poller as below:

```
    <int:channel id="transaction_jdbc1_InputChannel">
        <int:queue message-store="dataMessageStore"/>
    </int:channel>

    <int:chain input-channel="transaction_jdbc1_InputChannel" output-channel="transaction_jdbc1_OutputChannel">
        <int:poller fixed-delay="1000" error-channel="alertChannel">
            <int:transactional transaction-manager="txManager"/>
        </int:poller>
        <int:transformer ref="jsonToXmlTransformer"/>
    </int:chain>

    <bean id="txManager" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager" >
        <property name="dataSource" ref="mysqlDataSource"/>
    </bean>
```

The problem is that if the input message is invalid json string, the poller just gets it over and over, and other messages never get processed.

Is there any way to commit the transaction even meets exception? since we'll receive alert

Or there is better solution for reliable delivery?

Many Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Add a `<gateway reply-timeout="0" ... />` after the poller and call the `<transformer/>` downstream of the gateway's request channel.

Add an error channel to the gateway; on that error flow, check the exception type and, if it's a fatal error (e.g. bad JSON), don't throw an exception, and the transaction will be committed, and the flow will end. For all other exceptions, re-throw from the error flow and the transaction will roll back.

Comment: thanks for the reply, also found org.springframework.integration.transaction.TransactionHandleMessageAdvice or similar <tx:advice/> are more straightforward